# Как привязать высоту блока к его ширине?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как привязать **высоту** блока к его **ширине**? (не к ширине окна, а именно ширине блока)

Comment: var height = $("div").height();  $("div").css({ "width": height+"px" });

Comment: Вам для чего такое нужно? (есть разные подходы)

Answer (score 4):

**С помощью CSS**

```css
.ratio {
    width: 50%; /* здесь можно установить любую нужную ширину */
}

.ratio-inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    border: none;
}

.ratio-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

.ratio-4-3 {
 padding-top: 75%; /* Соотношение 4 к 3 */
}

.ratio-5-1 {
 padding-top: 20%; /* Соотношение 5 к 1 */
}
```

```html
<div class="ratio">
    <div class="ratio-inner ratio-4-3">
        <div class="ratio-content">
            Это содержимое блока 4/3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="ratio">
    <div class="ratio-inner ratio-5-1">
        <div class="ratio-content">
            Это содержимое блока 5/1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**С помощью JS**

```js
$(function(){
  $('.ratio').height($('.ratio').width()*0.75); // Соотношение 4 к 3

  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('.ratio').height($('.ratio').width()*0.75);
  });
});
```

```css
.ratio {
    background: #eee;
    width: 50%; /* здесь можно установить любую нужную ширину */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ratio">Это содержимое блока 4/3</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Еще можно поставить "распорку" в виде SVG

```css
.outer {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  margin : auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 16 9"></svg>
  <div class="inner">16x9</div>
</div>
```