# Соотношение сторон у адаптивного блока

Tags: html, css, видео

Есть блок с видео, который должен растягиваться на всю ширину и высоту экрана сохраняя пропорции 4:3, как задать эти самые пропорции?

```
<div class="intercom-content intercom-flex">
 <div class="filter">
  <video class="intercom-video"></video>
 </div>
</div>

.intercom-content {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #e5e9ed;
 margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
 overflow: auto;
 display: table;
 position: relative;
}

.intercom-video {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #cbcbcb;
}

.filter {
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #72879c;
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 display: table-cell;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: должен растягиваться на всю ширину и высоту экрана сохраняя пропорции 4:3. Звучит как взаимоисключающие требования

Comment: на всю возможную ширину, а по высоте растягиваться до пропорций 4:3. коряво написал, но суть вроде ясна

Comment: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: пробовал задать паддингом, видео все равно сохраняет пропорции 2 к 1

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792395/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5/792432#792432