# Как на css сделать такой грид из картинок?

Tags: css, sass

Добрый день! 
Подскажите, как можно реализовать данный грид для картинок? Интересует именно в таком виде и чтобы сохранялись альбомные пропорции картинок. Сортировка будет на Изотопе. Поэтому интересует именно css для разбивки блоков.[image: Грид из картинок]

Comment: Может, вам плагин https://masonry.desandro.com/ подойдет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такой шаблон на **Flex**. Вертикальные и горизонтальные размеры элементов надо будет подобрать вручную или вычислить математически.

Что бы сохранялась пропорция вертикальных и горизонтальных размеров при масштабировании, если стоит такая задача смотрим [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792395/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5).

```css
.all {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 30%;
}

.item-left {
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 80px;
}

.item-right {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 53px;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="item-left">1</div>
    <div class="item-left">2</div>
    <div class="item-left">3</div>
    <div class="item-left">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="item-right">1</div>
    <div class="item-right">2</div>
    <div class="item-right">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```